# JHipster generated code - LinkedList vs List

Tags: java, jhipster

I was wondering why it was chosen to use a LinkedList in the generated code for AccountResource.getAccount()?

```
/**
 * GET  /account -> get the current user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getAccount() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(userService.getUserWithAuthorities())
        .map(user -> {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new UserDTO(
                    user.getLogin(),
                    null,
                    user.getFirstName(),
                    user.getLastName(),
                    user.getEmail(),
                    user.getLangKey(),
                    user.getAuthorities().stream().map(Authority::getName).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))),
                HttpStatus.OK);
        })
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
}
```

The last argument in the UserDTO constructor "roles", a List of Strings. This is pulled out of the User record's Authority set, a HashSet. Not sure why a LinkedList is used rather than just a list, like:

```
...
user.getAuthorities().stream().map(Authority::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())),
...
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I'm just now transitioning to Java 8 and my Lambda knowledge is far from complete.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I wrapped the new ResponseEntity as an object { }.  Before that Intellij was complaining: **Cannot resolve method 'collect(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object.capture<?>,java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.Object>>)'**

Answer (score 0):

It's open source, so let's look at the source code, do a blame, and we find: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/63a02d6e711c535f92821479c83c695cd1c340d6. Apparently only done to remove a warning in IDEA.

Comment: Thanks JP.  Funny I have code just as the author changed from.  The only difference is I had to wrap in an object to make Intellij happy.  It seems to work fine:

Answer (score 0):

With `Collectors.toList()` you can not specify the implementation class.

The javadoc:

> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new
>   List. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability,
>   serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more
>   control over the returned List is required, use
>   toCollection(Supplier).

And a `LinkedList` is ideal for short lists of just a couple of items. That seems very adequate for authorities of which you are likely to have just one item. An ArrayList for instance would allocate an array.

Comment: Thanks Joop.  Maybe it was for the thread safety.  Although I would expect roles to be added at design time and be fixed.  Considering it's a get method, I'd think dirty reads are fine.  I just wanted to understand if there was something more to this ... a basic point I was missing.